# Android Google Cloud Messaging concept

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I've recently started working with Android's Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) and I'm having a hard time understanding the basic concepts of how GCM works.

According to what I understand at the moment, basically, we have 3 tier in the whole architecture:

1st Level - My Server
2nd Level - Google's Messaging Server
3rd Level - Client Android App

So what I understand is that every time a new user installs my android application, the app will registers itself with Google's server and get a "registration ID", and then it is supposed to connect to my server to let it know its registration ID, sort of "registering itself to the server".

My question is, is my server supposed to store every registration ID in my database in order for me to mass-publish a message to all the users with my android app installed? Or is there a method to "SEND MESSAGE TO ALL USERS" in GCM without the need of every single registration ID.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store registration IDs in your database.